Let $A_i$ be algebras for every $i$ and A is the product of $A_i$ such that $p_i: A\to A_i$ is the projection
Let $A_i$ be algebras for every $i$ and $A$ is the product of $A_i$ such that $p_i: A\to A_i$ is the projection and every algebra $A_i$ contains one-element subalgebra. Then exist homomorphisms $f_i: A_i \to A$, such that $p_if_i=1_Ai$. Show why the existence of one-element subalgebras is important.
This last part confuses be a little bit. I started by defining the map $f_i$ with $f_i(a_i)=(a_1,a_2,...)$. I also have that $p_i(a_1,a_2,...)=a_i$ and of course $1_Ai(a_i)=a_i$, so $p_if_i=1_Ai$. For $w_0$-nullary operation we have $f_i(w_0(A_i))=w_0(f_i(A_i))=w_0(A)$. When i take $w$ to be n-ary operation i'm starting to struggle. Also i'm wondering whether i should define the $f_i$ so include the one-element subalgebras. All in all i'm struggling to understand the importance of the one-element subalgebras. Any hint or explanation is greatly appreciated. Alos how do i write greek letters on here?

\to or \rightarrow makes $\to$

for greek letters and other formatting tips, see MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference. You can also check the links in the bottom of the page. There's plenty of useful stuff there. (I mean Tour and Help)

Hint: denote by $e_i$ (one of ) the element(s) of $A_i$ such that $\{e_i\}$ is a sub-algebra of $A_i$.
Define $f_i(a_i) = (e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{i-1}, a_i, e_{i+1}, \ldots, e_n)$.
Here, I'm assuming there are finitely many such algebras; for an infinite family, you can easily adapt.
Can you proceed from here?

Yes, thank you very much!
